# how to make application trusted

Tags: vb.net, security

vb.net applications that runs at the client-side work in unsecured environment, these applications connects to a mysql database server so... it contains the username and the password of the mysql database in the connection-string in the application itself.

isn't there any way to digitally sign my applications so the database server only accepts the requests from the trusted applications?

I want to this to prevent the hackers from hijacking my database

Answer (score 0):

Digitally signing your code won't help. While it's possible to run the connection through an SSL tunnel, that's some help - but you'll need to compile a native mysql client into your app rather than using ODBC (and I don't think such a thing exists).